# Linq 2 sql complex query (Count Issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Okay i am trying to write a query to get total Guest counts of each Zones, so far i failed :)

```
var Results = from g in DB.tblSecurityZones
              join PoliceStations in DB.tblPoliceStations
                  on g.SecurityZoneID equals PoliceStations.SecurityZoneID
              join Hotel in DB.tblHotels
                  on PoliceStations.PoliceStationID equals Hotel.PoliceStationID
              join HotelGuest in DB.tblGuests
                  on Hotel.HotelID equals HotelGuest.HotelID
              group g by new 
              { 
                  Zone = g.Name,
                  PoliceStation = PoliceStations.Name,
                  Hotel = Hotel.HotelName
              } into Result
              select new 
              {
                  Result.Key.Hotel,
                  Result.Key.PoliceStation,
                  Result.Key.Zone
              };
```

What i want is to Return Guest Counts from each zone.

I got HotelName, PoliceStationName and ZoneName but i cant figure out how to get GuestCounts also :S

Comment: Simply add `Result.Count()` in your anonymous type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select new 
{
    Result.Key.Hotel,
    Result.Key.PoliceStation,
    Result.Key.Zone,
    Count = Result.Count()
};
```